# Setter method not being called

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have this code:

.h

```
int cellsPerRow;

@property int cellsPerRow;
```

.m

```
@synthesize cellsPerRow;

-(void)init {
...
cellsPerRow = 4;
}

-(void)setCellsPerRow:(int)cellsPerRowLocal {
cellsPerRow = cellsPerRowLocal;
....
}
```

But the setter method isn't being called. Any ideas why?

Comment: I thought putting a property and synthesise meant it called the set and get methods automatically, but putting your own (which as you're typing it in becomes a suggestion). Once something else wasn't working as expected, i became suspicious and put an nslog in there, which didn't get called.

Comment: Your code looks correct but you’ve never shown where you’re actually calling the setter method, e.g. `obj.cellsPerRow = 5` or `[obj setCellsPerRow:5]`.

Comment: ah, sorry about that. i misunderstood you the first time. Updated.

Comment: I now see that the [self setCellsPerRow:4]; works, i thought the other method would work too. Is there a simple way to get the other method working?

Comment: As you can see, you’re not actually calling the setter method (see my comment above). You’re directly assigning a value to an instance variable.

Comment: No, it's not supposed to work like that. To explicitly call the method, use self.cellsPerRow = 4; .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property and synthesize create the setter and getter methods for you. In essence what you are doing is actually override the methods that were created for you in the first place.

Don't do that. Just use dot notation, like so, `self.cellsPerRow = cellsPerRowLocal`. This will set your `cellsPerRow` ivar to whatever you want it to be in `cellsPerRowLocal`.

In you header file:

```
int cellsPerRow;

@property (nonatomic, retain) int cellsPerRow;
```

In your implementation file:

```
@synthesize cellsPerRow;

- (void) inThisMethodYouSetcellsPerRow {

cellsPerRowLocal = ... ;

self.cellsPerRow = cellsPerRowLocal;

}
```

Comment: Note that there’s nothing wrong in overriding the setter method of a declared property. Also note that the dot syntax is not mandatory.

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning to the *variable* instead of the *property*. Instead of:

```
cellsPerRow = 4;
```

You need to do either:

```
self.cellsPerRow = 4;
```

or

```
[self setCellsPerRow:4];
```

The former is transformed by the compiler into the later, so they are equivalent.